# Unpacking a installer is failing with pkgutil tool

Tags: macos, pkg

when I am trying to unpack installer with (pkgutil --expand xyz.pkg output/path) it says "problem extracting file from package" output/path/XXX.bundle/contents/_codesignature/coderesources

What could be the possible reason for failure?

Answer (score 1):

It was the missing owner write permissions of the pkg that is causing the problem.